# Azure DevOps multiple branch build from another Azure DevOps project

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an inusual situation about creating builds. We have some solutions in a azure devops project and our builds and release management in another azure devops project.

In the design mode, when we are trying to create build from multiple branches, the branch specification hangs to infinite. I asume that this happens because this is not finding this repo in this project.

[image]

Comment: Report it as a bug on Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I have created a test on my own organization, it works properly in my side. Did this strange behavior only occurs on this project or all other projects ?

Comment: @jessehouwing I just created in the developercommunity.visualstudio.com.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT it's important to try from another azure devops project. In the same azure devops project it's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you already select the branch  in Azure Repos Git from Get source step

[image]

You should be able to see the branches in the Branch filters.

[image]

Actually according to your screenshot, this seems be some cache issue. Not sure if it's server side or client side.

Suggest you try to use another machine also give a test with some repos in other projects not only this project.

If this only occurs in your machine, please give a try with clear browser cache, which may do the trick.